# IOS-Programming Making event happen every time user moves finger 1cm

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe, touchesmoved

I am really new to IOS-programming and what I want to do is to make an event occur for every cm the user moves his finger on the screen. I also want different events to happen wether you are swiping left or right.

For example, if the user touches the screen and holds his finger still where he touched, i want nothing to happen, if he starts moving his finger to his left i want an event to occur(e.g a function being called) for every cm he moves his finger. same for if he starts moving his finger to the right but it should trigger a different event(function).

I would appreciate any help since i don´t know how to do this myself

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a pan gesture recognizer ([`UIPanGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). It's a little bit of math to get the behavior you are looking for, but it's possible.

Here is Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on gesture recongnizers: [UIGestureRecognizer Tutorial in iOS 5: Pinches, Pans, and More!](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)